# nodejs mysql not inserting data

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

so i have been getting two errors whenever im running my code through vscode terminal

1- i have created a connection to a database though xampp
2- i have html form to insert
3- server works

but i get these errors

Server Started! Listening on port 5001..
Error while creating Tourist! Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
C:\Users\may\Desktop\projectRun\routes\tourist.js:10
next(err);
^

ReferenceError: next is not defined
at C:\Users\may\Desktop\projectRun\routes\tourist.js:10:9
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

the route

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.json(await tourist.create(req.body));
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(``Error while creating Tourist!``, err.message);
        next(err);
    }
})
```

the html button that suppose to insert data and move to another page

````
  <input type="submit" value="Next" name="submit" onclick="submitTouristForm(); >```
````

Answer (score -1):

The error reference to next not defined because the name of the input is submit,
so it submits a variable with name submit and value = 'Next',
try change the name of the input .
The next it refer cuold have been even thatn with Next(err) try comment it

Comment: how can i fix it ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Try change the name of input and comment next(err)